# Kivymd error self._shadow = App.get_running_app().theme_cls.quad_shadow AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_cls'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am using kivy and kivymd.I am trying to create an MDToolbar inside a Screen. When i run i get the mentioned error. Hope you can help me out. Here is my `main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        #Get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name


MainApp().run()
```

And its `main.kv` file

```
#:include kv/homescreen.kv
#:include kv/settingsscreen.kv

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        HomeScreen:
            id: home_screen
            name: "home_screen"

        SettingsScreen:
            name: "settings_screen"
            id: settings_screen
```

I have my `homescreen.kv` written as:

```
#:import MDToolbar kivymd.uix.toolbar.MDToolbar
#:import utils kivy.utils

<HomeScreen>:
    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            name: 'nav_drawer'
            #drawer_logo: 'user.png'
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                icon: 'face'
                text: 'text'
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                icon: 'email'
                text: 'text'

            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                icon: 'phone'
                text: 'number'
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                icon: 'cake'
                text: 'date'
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                icon: 'city'
                text: 'city'
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                icon: 'settings'
                text: 'Settings'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#3983F2")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            MDToolbar:
                title: "Toolbar"
```

The error i get when i run is

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 696, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1318, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.trigger_change
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1333, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.trigger_change
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivymd/uix/elevation.py", line 111, in _update_shadow
     self._shadow = App.get_running_app().theme_cls.quad_shadow
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_cls'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/fypp/main.py", line 20, in <module>
     GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child, crule, rootrule, rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 657, in _apply_rule
     root=rctx['ids']['root'], rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child, crule, rootrule, rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child, crule, rootrule, rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 657, in _apply_rule
     root=rctx['ids']['root'], rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 707, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 22:
 ...
      20:<MDToolbar>
      21:    size_hint_y: None
 >>   22:    height: root.theme_cls.standard_increment
      23:    padding: [root.theme_cls.horizontal_margins - dp(12), 0]
      24:    opposite_colors: True
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'theme_cls'
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 696, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1318, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.trigger_change
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1333, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.trigger_change
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/home/pakomoaro/PycharmProjects/FYP/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivymd/uix/elevation.py", line 111, in _update_shadow
     self._shadow = App.get_running_app().theme_cls.quad_shadow
```

Comment: Can you run this and give us the answer "pip3 show kivymd" and "pip3 show kivy"

Comment: @PabloGod                                                                                                         Name: kivymd
Version: 0.102.1
Summary: Set of widgets for Kivy inspired by Google's Material Design
Home-page: https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD
Author: Andrés Rodríguez, fork author - HeaTTheatR
Author-email: kivydevelopment@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: kivy, pillow, requests
Required-by:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the current version of KivyMD (0.102.1), try to replace the `from kivy.app import App` with `from kivymd.app import MDApp` and then this:

```py
class MainApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    def build(self):
        return GUI
```

with this:

```py
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return GUI
```

You also have to change your `root widget` in your `main.kv`.
Its not wise to use a kivy widget as your `root` like this.

You must first create a class in your `.py`:

```py
class BaseWidget(GridLayout):
    pass
```

and change your `.kv`:

```py
<BaseWidget>:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        HomeScreen:
            id: home_screen
            name: "home_screen"

        SettingsScreen:
            name: "settings_screen"
            id: settings_screen
```

After that, you have to return your root widget in your `build` method:

```py
class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return BaseWidget()
```

Comment: Now it is giving me the error     App.get_running_app().property("theme_cls", True),
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'property'

Comment: @PakoMoaro Can you provide a [mcve]? There are things missing from your code (like the `settingsscreen.kv`)

Comment: @PakoMoaro See the updated answer. Its the best I can do without some runable code...